# Show number of occurrences in pivot_wider

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a dataset with 2 columns: State and Month.

[image]

I want to pivot this dataset to a wide format using pivot_wider() in r.
I tried the following

```
Data<- fm %>% group_by(State) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Month", values_from = "Month")
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I know that the values_from argument is incorrect but I want to know what needs to be done over there.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Could just use `dplyr::count(fm, State, Month)` to get a count of the occurrences.

Comment: Thank you so much!!. That does make the dataset simpler wondering why I didn't think of it earlier

Answer (score 1):

We may use `values_fn` to return `length` or if there are `NA` elements, get the count by the `sum` of non-NA elements

```
library(dplyr)
fm %>%   
    pivot_wider(names_from = "Month", values_from = "Month",
           values_fn = function(x) sum(!is.na(x)), values_fill = 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I did give a thought to values_fn but didn't have any prior experience with it so couldn't figure out how it works.